# Absolute positioning inside relative - using bottom: 0 doesn't seem to work

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to position an item relative to the bottom of a containing div.  Using position: relative for the parent and then position: absolute for the child elements seems to work as expected.  (I used [this article](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) as a reference.)

My problem is that when I change:

```
top: 0;
```

to

```
bottom: 0;
```

for one of the inner elements it jumps to the top of the containing div.  I want it to be relative to the bottom of the gray block.

Here's the code:

```css
 .channeldiv {
      margin: 0px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .channel_summary {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: gray;
    }
    
    .channel_wrap {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .inner_pink {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .inner_green {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .big_background {
      height: 73px;
      width: 128px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    
    .overlaytext {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: right;
      z-index: 3;
      background-color: black;
      color: lightgreen;
      font-family: monospace;
    }
    
    .trades_num {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 3;
      background-color: black;
      color: lightgray;
    }
```

```html
<div class="channeldiv">
      <div class="big_background">
        <div class="channel_summary">
          <div class="channel_wrap">
            <svg class="inner_green" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <rect id="rect1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
            </svg>
            <span class="overlaytext">+1.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="trades_num">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="channeldiv">
      <div class="big_background">
        <div class="channel_summary">
          <div class="channel_wrap">
            <svg class="inner_pink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <rect id="rect1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="pink" />
            </svg>
            <span class="overlaytext">+1.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="trades_num">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davemabe/h6cv7prs/

[image]

Comment: Please include code which reproduces the problem **in the question itself** not just on an external site. You can use Stack Snippets (icon in editor looks like `<>`) to do so.

Comment: If you had some code on a Codepen or likewise, it would be great. That way I can take a look. It may be that the wrapper set to relative isn't where you think it is. I tend to add borders in CSS to divs whilst working. Then I can see what is where. Happy to help if you have code :)

Comment: Just added the code.  Thanks!

Comment: If you remove `<div class="channel_wrap">` and its corresponding `</div>` does it produce the required design?

Comment: @andyb - actually yes it seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `position: relative;` in the `channel_wrap` class, because in this case it disables its child positioning. After doing that, it works as you wanted.

The article you suggested is just two positioning (absolute in relative) inside each other, whilst what you're trying to do is a triple one (absolute in relative in absolute) which doesn't result in what you expect it to.

In fact if you want to keep it triple like this, you need to at least give that `channel_wrap` div, e.g. a height, so that its children would know how to react to their parental positioning and only then they would know where they should be *bottomed* to.

More info about [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and [bottom](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp) property